# Return variable from database find instead of array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I need to pull two values out of my mongoDB database and right now the code is returning an array. How do I get:

1. totalGuests
2. attendedGuests

*out* of the query and stored in variables so I can display them on the client?

```
module.exports.showEvent = async(req, res,) => {
    const event = await Event.findById(req.params.id).populate('artist');
    if (!event) {
        req.flash('error', 'Cannot find that Event');
        return res.redirect('/events');
    }
    res.render('events/show', { event });
    const { guest_id } = req.cookies;
    const lookUp = Event.collection.find({ _id: req.params.id},
      {
        _id: 1,
        name: 1,
        guests: 1,
        totalGuests: {
          $size: "$guests"
        },
        attendedGuests: {
          $size: {
            "$filter": {
              input: "$guests",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.attended",
                  "Y"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
    console.log(lookUp);
```

Comment: Use `findOne` instead of `find`.

Comment: hi @J.F. that gives me "Promise { <pending> }" which makes me think I need a callback? I'm also querying by _id and the mongoose docs suggest using findById if that's the case. Basically, I'm very confused... https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find

Comment: Use `await`: `const lookUp = await Event.collection.findOne(...)` or use a promise: `Event.collection.findOne(...).then(/*code here*/).catch(/**/)`. As your method is async (and also you use `await` in `await Event.findById`) I think is easier if you use `await` here too.

Comment: I'm sorry @J.F. I do see where you're going but I don't have the experience to put it all together. Any chance you would be willing to format the code as an answer?